# SQLITE error or missing database (no such table: Path)

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlconnection

```
 try {
        // db parameters
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite: db_path.db";
        // create a connection to the database
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        System.out.println("Connection to SQLite has been established.");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

When database is connected a duplicate file is created with same name and size 0Kb inside project folder

```
String query = "INSERT INTO Path VALUES (?)";

try {
    PreparedStatement state = DB_Path.conn.prepareStatement(query);
    state.setString(1,path);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in url of database file i-e space between jdbc:sqlite: and db_path.db

The correct way is:

```
url = "jdbc:sqlite:db_path.db;
```

You can use absolute path too but keep in mind the above line of error, for locating some file in directory, it preferable to use backward slash b/w directories because it is used in windows path system and for java syntax it comes two times like this,

```
url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Desktop\\db_path.db;
```

or you can use forward slash too,

```
url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/Desktop/db_path.db;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your connection does not have permissions to access the existing db file. So it creates a new (different) file

Comment: Can u help, how to fix it? Please!